# OIDC Error after adding Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens

Tags: c#, openid-connect, .net-8.0

I am using multiple Authentications in my .net 8 webapi (Cookie, OIDC, JWT). When I am adding only the reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens im getting the error below.

**Error**

> Cannot redirect to the authorization endpoint, the configuration may
> be missing or invalid.

WebApi.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.8.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.8.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.8.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="7.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Authentication Configuration

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        //sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        //sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        var oidc = new OidcOptions();
        configuration.GetSection(OidcOptions.Key).Bind(oidc);

        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        options.Scope.Clear();
        oidc.Scopes.ForEach(options.Scope.Add);
        options.Authority = oidc.Authority;
        options.ClientId = oidc.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = oidc.ClientSecret;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
            {
                var authEndpoint = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress;
                // Debug or log the authEndpoint here to inspect its value
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

For Some reason the issuer url is not set in the middleware. But only when I am adding the Jwt dependency.